# Migrate nodejs from mongo atlas to mongodb 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a server admin, need to install nodejs script that will use local mongodb instead of connecting using URL to mongo atlas cloud servers.

As server admin I thought that its like instead of using URL we use localhost instead.

The script uses Mongoose & nodeJS to connect to mongodb. When I try to start script using node I got the following error :

> ReferenceError: MONGODBURI is not defined

I uses the following code so that I can use NodeJS and mongoose to connect to Mongodb

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://server.hostname:27017/testMain", {
  "auth": { "authSource": "admin" },
  "user": "testUser2",
  "pass": "abc123H"
}).then(res => {
  console.log("connected")
}).catch(err => {
    const error = new Error(err);
    error.httpStatusCode = 500;
    return next(error);

  });

const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODBURI,
  collection: "sessions"
});
```

I think that the problem is that "MongoDBStore" requires URI.

BTW, I tested connecting to Mongodb using nodeJS & mongoose without authentication & works fine!

How could I solve this issue?

Are there any replacement to "MongoDBStore" or workaround for this situation?
Please any help will be appreciated
Thanks all in advance,

Comment: I have changed the code to be as follows
```
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: "mongodb://testUser2:abc123H@serv01.hostname.com:27017",
  databaseName:'testMain',
  collection: "sessions"
},
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);

  })

```
Now when i run node index.js the script seems working in shell, but no nodejs port is listening & also when visiting website it shows source code instead of running it , what could be the reason ? why nodejs doesnt listen on port 3000 when i run command ? i never use any port to listen on it, why nodejs doesnt startup correctly ?

Comment: Where are you defining `MONGODBURI`? I do not see it in the provided code block. This just looks like an instance of an undefined variable.